# How to get dump from a neo4j in docker?

Tags: docker, neo4j

```
docker run -d -v /home/data:/data --name=neo neo4j
```

after I run a neo4j in docker,
`docker exec -it neo bash`

```
./neo4j-admin  dump --database=graph.db --to=/home/2018.dump
```

it will say neo4j is running
`command failed: the database is in use -- stop Neo4j and try again`

but `./neo4j stop` will get `neo4j not running`

what should i do?

Comment: I believe this addresses your problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/835092/how-do-you-perform-a-dump-of-a-neo4j-database-within-a-docker-container

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before, so I wrote this workaround to dump neo4j data and pull it outside the container to the host machine.

```
docker rm --force neo4j-dump

docker run \
--name neo4j-dump \
--env-file /storage/bin/.neo4j.env \
--mount type=bind,source=<neo4j_data_folder>,target=/data \
neo4j bin/neo4j-admin dump --database=graph.db --to=/graph.db.dump

docker cp `docker ps -aqf "name=neo4j-dump"`:/graph.db.dump <target_dump_file>

docker rm --force neo4j-dump
```

This will create a new container and dump data instead of starting neo4j service, then copy the dump to the host,
just update  and  to yours